# How to master English prepositions?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, english, grammar

I have been trying to learn English prepositions so many times but so far I have failed. It is the only thing that gives me so much pain. I have watched so many movies or videos and also read many books but that doesn't help me much.

Is there any better option to master prepositions? I also get confused about the use prepositions because many prepositions work the same as other ones.

Comment: You can start here: https://www.uvic.ca/learningandteaching/cac/assets/docs/Prepositions%20Final.pdf One point though: there are a few instances where AmE speakers and BrE speakers use different prepositions. For example: I saw him in the High Street [BrE] versus I saw him on Main Street [AmE].

Answer (score 1):

One problem you may have is dealing with prepositions that are used with phrasal verbs (get through, set off, bring about). Don't learn those separately from the verb they are used with, because they tend to lose their literal meaning when used with phrasal verbs (where does a bomb blow up to?). Imagine they are a part of the word, just like un- is a part of unusual.

As for locational prepositions, you may want to grab a small paper, draw a box and write prepositions around it. You'll have easy reference to the prepositions you need without having to carry a dictionary all the time.